# Nested function decorators that operate on arguments in python

Tags: python, decorator, inspect, keyword-argument

I am writing a function decorator that will apply a conversion to the first argument of the function. It works fine if I only decorate my functions once but if I decorate them twice I get an error. Below is some code that demonstrates the problem, it is a simplified version of the code I'm working on. I have excluded the code that does the conversion so as to not distract from the problem

```
from inspect import getargspec
from functools import wraps

def dec(id):
    def _dec(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def __dec(*args, **kwargs):
            if len(args):
                return fn(args[0], *args[1:], **kwargs)
            else:
                first_arg = getargspec(fn).args[0]
                new_kwargs = kwargs.copy()
                del new_kwargs[first_arg]
                return fn(kwargs[first_arg], **new_kwargs)
        return __dec
    return _dec

@dec(1)
def functionWithOneDecorator(a, b, c):
    print "functionWithOneDecorator(a = %s, b = %s, c = %s)" % (a, b, c)

@dec(1)
@dec(2)
def functionWithTwoDecorators(a, b, c):
    print "functionWithTwoDecorators(a = %s, b = %s, c = %s)" % (a, b, c)

functionWithOneDecorator(1, 2, 3)
functionWithOneDecorator(1, b=2, c=3)
functionWithOneDecorator(a=1, b=2, c=3)
functionWithOneDecorator(c=3, b=2, a=1)

functionWithTwoDecorators(1, 2, 3)
functionWithTwoDecorators(1, b=2, c=3)
functionWithTwoDecorators(a=1, b=2, c=3)
functionWithTwoDecorators(c=3, b=2, a=1)
```

When I run the above code I get the following output:

```
functionWithOneDecorator(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
functionWithOneDecorator(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
functionWithOneDecorator(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
functionWithOneDecorator(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
functionWithTwoDecorators(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
functionWithTwoDecorators(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is because when the second decorator inspects the function it is decorating to find the argument names and fails because it is decorating a decorator and that only takes *args and **kwargs.

I can think of ways around the problem which would work in the code above but would still break if a function was decorated with my decorator and another from a 3rd party. Is there a general way to fix this? or is there a better way to achieve the same result?

**Update:** Thanks to @Hernan for pointing out the [decorator module](http://micheles.googlecode.com/hg/decorator/documentation.html). It solves this problem exactly. Now my code looks like this:

```
from decorator import decorator

def dec(id):
    @decorator
    def _dec(fn, *args, **kwargs):
        return fn(args[0], *args[1:], **kwargs)
    return _dec

@dec(1)
def functionWithOneDecorator(a, b, c):
    print "functionWithOneDecorator(a = %s, b = %s, c = %s)" % (a, b, c)

@dec(1)
@dec(2)
def functionWithTwoDecorators(a, b, c):
    print "functionWithTwoDecorators(a = %s, b = %s, c = %s)" % (a, b, c)

functionWithOneDecorator(1, 2, 3)
functionWithOneDecorator(1, b=2, c=3)
functionWithOneDecorator(a=1, b=2, c=3)
functionWithOneDecorator(c=3, b=2, a=1)

functionWithTwoDecorators(1, 2, 3)
functionWithTwoDecorators(1, b=2, c=3)
functionWithTwoDecorators(a=1, b=2, c=3)
functionWithTwoDecorators(c=3, b=2, a=1)
```

Much cleaner, and **it works!**

Comment: Why `args[0], *args[1:]`, it is the same as `*args`?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this decorator? As far as I can tell it's main goal seems to be to make sure that the first given argument - keyword/optional or otherwise - is alway passed to the wrapped function as it's "first" argument. Also, what is the intended significance of the `id` argument to the decorator? It's not used anywhere.

Comment: I want to apply a conversion to the first argument. In the code supplied above I excluded the code that does the conversion so as to not distract from the problem.

Comment: In the real code I want to be able to define a number of different decorators that each does a different conversion on the first argument of the function. I want to be able to apply more than one of these decorators to a given function as well as possibly other 3rd party decorators. The id is just there to  model having a number of these decorators - if you like the id is the id of the conversion to be applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the signature of your decorated function is not the signature (getargspec) from the original. It is really well explained in the help of the [decorator module](http://micheles.googlecode.com/hg/decorator/documentation.html) which you can to solve your problem. Basically, you should use a signature-preserving decorators, so that the second decorator sees the same signature as the first.